# Editing Source code of AChart Engine (Pie Chart)

Tags: android, charts, achartengine, pie-chart

i am trying to edit the source code of AChart Engine which is very good,

1. I need to reduce the margin above the pie chart i have tried with renderer.setMargins() but not working,and also i need the chart to be bit bigger which should work for all screen sizes.
2. I have added the pie chart to a LinerLayout and i have a Scroll View to that linear layout but when i scroll down the pie chart shrinks.
3. There is some margin below thew legends how to remove that?

please share your views on this and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I told you before that you are asking several questions in a single one. However, I will answer them anyway:

1. Play with the value you pass to the `renderer.setScale()` method.
2. Use `renderer.setInScroll(true)`.
3. Use `renderer.setFitLegend(true)`.

Comment: i am trying to edit the source code, so that i can make it according to my requirement i am sorry for disturbing you again

Comment: i need your help in editing the source code can you please help me

Comment: can we go to a seperate chat room?

Comment: i have that copy and now i need to have 2 things to be done please help on that, how to increase the size of pie chart which is drawn ?

Comment: Did you read the answer I have just gave to your question? You don't have to modify the ACE source code. Just call renderer.setScale(2) for instance.

Comment: thanks a lot, but renderer.setInScroll(true). is not working for me? i have added in AbstractDemoChart class in buildCategoryRenderer method

Comment: here is the code http://pastie.org/5701771 and here is the screen shot http://i.imgur.com/nq18P.png

Comment: Your code doesn't contain anything from my answers on your questions #1 and #3.

Comment: you can see in AbstractDemoChart i have added in buildCategoryRenderer method renderer.setInScroll(true). but its not working any mistake that i am doing?

Comment: how to pass the gradient colors to slices?

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd case use `renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);` and `renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);`

Comment: do you know how to increase the size off the pie chart?